# A technique for responsiveness using CSS transform scale

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm wondering how to make a website responsive using CSS scale property.

Basically the code would detect the window width and scale the elements accordingly, but there is a problem, when you use:

```
transform:scale(1.3);
```

for exemple, the element which the scale is applied to mantains its CSS size, so, I would imagine it's impossible to gather the actual size of the element on the screen by javascript, which makes it impossible to calculate how much it should scale.

Any ideas on how to work on this? Is it even possible to scale according to window size?

Comment: It is possible to scale on the basis of window or screen width. Though simple media queries are a much better solution. Scaling for responsiveness is just a hack that I had to sometimes use for canvas based browser games.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to scale according to window size using CSS. max-width: 50%; would keep the element at 50% of the browser width.

Run the code snippet in full page and resize your browser.

Is that what you meant? forgive me if I've misunderstood. :)

```css
.max-width {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  max-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="max-width">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Right Way of adapar a div to the screen resolution , is with **percentages** or using the properties of "**max-width**" and "**min-width**" .

For more comodida recommend [bootstrap](http://codeappweb.blogspot.com/2016/04/personalizar-estilos-bootstrap.html)